# multiple input fields on text change

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

We are working on a large form and there is 1 option for selecting installments for user, so we are using form select to show duration like 6 12 18 24 30 36 and it should give 6 boxes if admin selects 6 with 2 input fields DATE and Amount after that it should be saved to mysql using php, so can you give some advice or code please? thanks...

Comment: What have you done. Where's the code that you need help with...

Comment: Sure, my advice would be to learn the basics of html, css, javascript, php and mysql and try to put it together. Then either you don't need any more help or you can post the code that you have so that you can get help with it. No one is going to spend the time writing your whole application for you... without compensation.

Answer (score 0):

For the client side you can use the below jQuery script 
Working [**example here**](http://jsfiddle.net/mrobin/AA4Ud/6/)

```
Enter Duration: <input type="text" id="duration" />
<button>Go</button><br />
<form id="orders">
</form>
```

And the javascript..

```
<script>
$('button').click(function(){
    var count = parseInt($('#duration').val(), 10);
    if(!isNaN(count)){
        for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
            $('#orders').append(i+". ").append("<input class='item' /><br />");
        }
       }
});
</script>
```

For the MySQL php part there are numerous examples available out there and a little googling will certainly help.

Comment: if i first write 6 and then again write 7 then 12 box appears, please modify your code a bit

Comment: thanks for your support, and how can we submit it to mysql using php?

Comment: @diEcho:Thanks for pointing out. I have fixed the same and updated the link.

Answer (score 0):

@seopps AFAIU you want a raw format, how to develope a form and proceed further, i m giving u just a hint, you can manipulate/modify according to your need

#### installment.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select').change(function () {
        $('div#wayofpay').show();
    });
});
</script>



<form method="post" action="nextpage.php">
    <select name="installment" id="installment">
        <option value=''>Select Duration:</option>
        <?php foreach(range(0,36,6) as $ts) { ?>
        <option value='<?php echo $ts?>'><?php echo $ts;?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>

    <div id="wayofpay" style="display:none">
    <label for='start_date'>Date:</label><input type="text" name="start_date" id="start_date" value="">
    <label for='amount'>Amount:</label><input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" value="">
    </div>
</form>
```

#### nextpage.php

```
$post_data = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string',$_POST);
// create mysql connection and use below query

$qry= "INSERT INTO yourtable SET
                                  installment_duration = $post_data['installment'];
                                  start_date=$post_data['start_date'];
                                  amount =$post_data['amount'] ";
mysql_query($qry);
```